# Professional editing of a thesis

Tags: phd, thesis, legal-issues, copy-editing

I am a professional freelance editor. I edited a thesis and subsequently the candidate has refused to pay my fee. Can I claim intellectual property rights over those editing changes and require the candidate not to use them in their submitted or published thesis?

Comment: "_I edited a thesis_" Is this legal in your country?

Comment: @scaaahu it is fairly common when the thesis is written in English by a non native speaker. I see no problem in that, neither legal nor moral. The thesis is supposed to show that the candidate can do independent research. Letting somebody else check the English is good practice in real research, so why not during the thesis?

Comment: @MaartenBuis I think it depends on what the OP meant by "edit". If the OP simply fixed the grammar errors, what is the "_intellectual property rights_" the OP is talking about?

Comment: @scaaahu my suspicion is that the OP is thinking in the wrong direction. Instead of property rights (s)he should think in terms of a contract.

Comment: @MaartenBuis: "The thesis is supposed to show that the candidate can do independent research" - well, it depends on the amount of editing necessary, but the thesis is *also*, *somehow*, useful for showing that the PhD candidate is able to present their work in a coherent text that is usable without excessive efforts in post-processing. Indeed, I consider that a part of "doing independent research" (or, let's say, doing pretty much anything related to information or knowledge independently).

Comment: If the editor understands the text, then that condition is fulfilled as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Professional editing of theses is common practice in Australia, even when the candidate is a native English speaker. Editing can involve more than spelling and grammar; it can improve the expression by reformulating, adjusting syntax, eliminating repetition and suggesting alternative vocabulary. The editor will understand the principles of clear academic style and discourse. However, editing changes must be confined to the level of language use and not affect the organisation or structure of the thesis.

Answer (score 6):

I think you'd be well within your rights to take the offender to **[Small Claims Court](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/small-claims-court)** for non-payment.

Comment: Thanks for that advice and it's probably what I will do.

Comment: @mochaval No problem. Good luck.